# A non well formed numeric value encountered blade php in Pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I am trying to display the number of items displayed in page in php pagination. Here is my code:

```
@if ($result->onFirstPage())
     {{1 . '~' . $result->count()}}
@else
    {{(($result->currentPage()-1)*12)+1 . '~' . + (($result->currentPage()-1)*12) + $result->count() }}
@endif
```

I've tried typecasting them to int but still not working. This calculation `(($result->currentPage()-1)*12)` works well but if I add the `$result->count()` it returns the `non well formed numeric value` error. How can I possibly fix this one? Some suggestions on how to solve this one are not working.

Comment: what is the value in $result->count()

Comment: @Shibon It is a whole number. It is the count of the items in a page displayed.

Comment: {{(($result->currentPage()-1)*12)+1 . '~' . + (($result->currentPage()-1)*12) + $result->count() }} for what purpose u are using this can you explain along with the question

Comment: @Shibon It is stated in the question already. I want to show like `1~10 items` on first page, `11-20` on second page like that.

Comment: You have added an extra +

Comment: @Shibon I have tried that if you can see on my question that it works well, but when adding the `+ $result->count()` now returns the error.

Comment: @Shibon `try like this {{(($result->currentPage()-1)*12)+1 . '~' . (($result->currentPage()-1)*12) + $result->count() }}` is what I have currently now. Seems that you're re stating what I have in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay got it. I just enclosed them in one parenthesis!

```
((($result->currentPage()-1)*12) + $result->count())
```

So my line will look like this:

```
{{(($result->currentPage()-1)*12)+1 . '~' . + ((($result->currentPage()-1)*12) + $result->count()) }}
```

Comment: echo (((10-1)*12)+1) . "~" .  (((10-1)*12) + 20);

Comment: @Shibon Thanks for that, but what I'm passing are not static.

Comment: just an nexample